# How many negative integers $m$ are there so that $(x^2+x+m)^2 \geq (x^2-3x-m)^2$ is true for every $x > 0$

Tags: inequality

I came across the above-mentioned problem in my math test. I've tried:

1. Moving all the squares to one side: $$(x^2+x+m)^2-(x^2-3x-m)^2 \geq 0$$
2. Use the equality $A^2-B^2=(A-B)(A+B)$: $$(4x+2m)(2x^2-2x) \geq 0$$
   But solving the second polynomial never gives $x>0$ ($2x^2-2x \geq 0$ gives $x \geq 1 \lor x \leq 0$, $2x^2-2x \leq 0$ gives $0 \leq x \leq 1$, which doesn't contain every $x > 0$). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a cubic:
  $$ f(x) = x(x-1)(2x + m) \geq 0$$
Two of the roots of the cubic are $0$ and $1$. We need $f(x) \geq 0$ so the graph of the cubic must be above the $x$ axis between $0$ and $1$. The only way the function can then proceed without becoming negative after the root at $x=1$ is if $1$ is a repeated root. Thus, the factor $2x+m$ must again give us the root $x = 1$. We have $2x + m = 0 \Rightarrow x = -\frac{m}{2}$ so we need $m=-2$ to ensure $1$ is a repeated root. Thus, there is only one possibility: $m = -2$.

Answer (score 2):

After simplifying what you have, including dividing by all positive factors on LHS, you get $(2x+m)(x-1)\geqslant 0$.

Now for $x<1$, you need the first factor to be non-positive, and for $x>1$ it must be non-negative.  ie. $m=-2$.